# Vuejs How to assign value to select options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my `vue`-application  I want to assign some values from an `xls`-file to some options in a select.

```
<tr v-for="header in fileHeaders" :key="header">
   <td>{{header}}</td>
   <td>
     <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedField" v-on:change="setField">
        <option selected>Choose option</option>
        <option value="company_name">Company name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
        <option value="zipcode">Zipcode</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="number">Phonenumber</option>
        <option value="contact_person">Contact person</option>
        <option value="cvr_number">ID</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

data() {
  return {
    fileHeaders: ['Company Name', 'Zipcode', 'City' etc.],
    selectedField: "",
    chosenFields: []
  };
}
```

so for each `{{header}}` I want to assign a specific option from the select and then I want to push an array to the backend with the assigned values but I don't really know how to achieve that or where to start...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you also add the data contained in fileHeaders?

Comment: @Amaarrockz I've added the fileHeaders data. Please check the updated question

Comment: So now all you wanted to do is use them as options in your select menu right?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement...what you want to do here?

Comment: @Amaarrockz It is really hard to explain...

Comment: Can you also share the array of data that you want to push to the backend?

Comment: So let me ask like this...what problem do you have with the current code?

Answer (score 0):

just use **chosenFields[]** as v-model of select with index **i** of v-for. you will get selected values in chosenFields array

```
<tr v-for="(header,i) in fileHeaders" :key="header">
   <td>{{header}}</td>
   <td>
     <select class="form-control" v-model="chosenFields[i]" v-on:change="setField">
        <option selected>Choose option</option>
        <option value="company_name">Company name</option>
        <option value="address">Address</option>
        <option value="zipcode">Zipcode</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
        <option value="email">Email</option>
        <option value="number">Phonenumber</option>
        <option value="contact_person">Contact person</option>
        <option value="cvr_number">ID</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
    
    data() {
      return {
        fileHeaders: ['Company Name', 'Zipcode', 'City' etc.],
        selectedField: "",
        chosenFields: []
      };
    }
```